# How Can I parse an xml with empty tags using NSXMLParser?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, null, nsxmlparser

How to parse the xml tags with empty values to get null values using NSXMLParser. I'm using the following code :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Video"])
    {
        isStatus = YES;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ArrayOfVideo"])
    {
        isStatus = NO;
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (isStatus)
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"MediaOriginalFileName"])
        {
            [originalFileAry addObject:currentNodeContent];
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"MediaType"])
        {
            [typeArray addObject:currentNodeContent];
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"VideoMediaSource"])
        {
            [tableda addObject:currentNodeContent];
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"VideoThumbnail"])
        {
            [tableImg addObject:currentNodeContent];
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"VideoTitle"])
        {
            [tableData addObject:currentNodeContent];
        }
    }
}
```

here I'm not getting the empty values for the tag "VideoThumbnail".. Please help me to solve this...

Comment: Please post your xml structure also

Comment: my xml structure is something like this:  <root><title>xyz</title>< <MediaOriginalFileName>xyz</MediaOriginalFileName><VideoThumbnail/><videoTitle>asdfg</videoTitle></root>

Comment: <Video>
<IsPrivate>false</IsPrivate>
<MediaOriginalFileName>
c02a3ea9-15dc-420e-b994-8dc708ccabbcjinglebells.mp3
</MediaOriginalFileName>
<MediaType>Audio</MediaType>
<OverlayText/>
<VideoDescription>sdd</VideoDescription>
<VideoFullTitle>jinglebells.mp3</VideoFullTitle>
<VideoID>c8e0d29f-7567-4249-860e-325be36b1216</VideoID>
<VideoLikes>0</VideoLikes>
<VideoMediaSource>
c02a3ea9-15dc-420e-b994-8dc708ccabbcjinglebells.mp3
</VideoMediaSource>
<VideoShortTitle>sd</VideoShortTitle>
<VideoTags/>
<VideoThumbnail/>
<VideoTitle>jinglebells.mp3</VideoTitle>
<VideoViews>29</VideoViews>
</Video>

Comment: here i need the thumnail value after parsing as empty or null

Comment: your `VideoThumbnail` don't have any data, that's why you are getting empty value / null so what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to get that empty value in an array after parsing. but I'm not getting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i tried ,and i found empty string, as expected from your example.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"the tag is %@",elementName);
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"VideoThumbnail"])
    {
        NSLog(@"video thumbnail tag arrived");
        datastringThumbnail =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
 if(datastringThumbnail)
 {
   datastringThumbnail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
 }


}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
  {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"VideoThumbnail"])
        NSLog(@"the string is : %@",datastringThumbnail);
    // [tableImg addObject:currentNodeContent];

    //  currentNodeContent is datastringThumbnail in my case
}
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"the string we get is %@",datastringThumbnail);
}
```

FYI, datastringThumbnail is mutable string that will store you data of thumbnail tag(if any). As in your case there was no data in that tag, this string was empty. Use it wherever you want.

Comment: @ user2553590  It's been a few weeks, but if this solved your problem can you please mark my answer as correct. I need reputation on StackOverflow...that's how things work here if your unfamiliar

Answer (score 0):

Actually, thing is that your method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

{

}

is not being called since there are no data inside that particular data. So in following method ,you can do as follow :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

{

```
if (isStatus)
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"VideoThumbnail"])
    {
        if([currentContent Length]>0)
        {
        [tableImg addObject:currentNodeContent];
        }
        else
        {
            [tableImg addObject:@" "];
         }
    }

}
```

}

forgive my indentation... Also TBXML parsing is much faster and easier way to work with xml parsing. you can directly give names of tags and their child nodes.

Comment: But in - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string  method also i'm not getting the empty values.. string is not returning any empty values

Comment: Please write your xml, that would be great help.
and there is no special symbol to show that there is some kind of empty value,  if your string mentioned in above method remains empty that itself signifies that there was no data.

Comment: <Video>
<IsPrivate>false</IsPrivate>
<MediaOriginalFileName>
ED06EEF9-CD20-41AE-BDD4-068681F972E7Archive_20130606_01.02.47.asf
</MediaOriginalFileName>
<MediaType>Audio</MediaType>
<OverlayText/>
<VideoDescription/>
<VideoFullTitle>audiotest2.mp3</VideoFullTitle>
<VideoID>63a33633-4f67-46c5-8574-22ef35257603</VideoID>
<VideoLikes>0</VideoLikes>
<VideoMediaSource>
ED06EEF9-CD20-41AE-BDD4-068681F972E7Archive.asf
</VideoMediaSource>
<VideoShortTitle>audiotest2.mp3</VideoShortTitle>
<VideoTags/>
<VideoThumbnail/>
<VideoTitle>audiotest2.mp3</VideoTitle>
<VideoViews>1</VideoViews>
</Video>

Comment: In the above xml file VideoThumbnail tag value is null

Answer (score 0):

You try in

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

May be you get the getting the empty values for the tag "VideoThumbnail".

Following link useful for you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SeismicXML/Listings/SeismicXML_APLParseOperation_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323-SeismicXML_APLParseOperation_m-DontLinkElementID_11